# Get session id in tomcat access logs for angular js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, tomcat

We are trying to print session id in access logs using `'%S'` in `server.xml`. The application is developed using angular js.

However it prints **"-"** instead of session id.

**server.xml**

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="sessionId=%S host=%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

**Access Logs:**

```
sessionId=- host=127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2017:13:44:32 +0100] "GET /application/img/sort-icn-down.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1114
```

Does angular js application create session id automatically?

Comment: We cannot help you unless you specify how your server handles sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Session ID will only show if your server side application creates one, and that depends on the framework you're using... Spring MVC, for example, always creates a new Session ID if there's no Session ID in the request.

Let me show a simple test I did with a Spring MVC project and Tomcat:

Consider the following snippet from my server.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b session-id %S" />
```

Consider that I don't have any cookies in my first access opening an image:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2017:18:40:53 -0300] "GET /webapp/images/login.png HTTP/1.1" 200 29646 session-id -
```

Since it's a image that is not handled by Spring, my server won't create a session id... Accessing again will not help

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2017:18:42:52 -0300] "GET /webapp/images/login.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - session-id -
```

But if I access a method handled by Spring MVC it will create a new session (and I don't have full control over the session's creation)

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2017:18:45:16 -0300] "GET /webapp/pages/users.json HTTP/1.1" 200 110 session-id 068FCCF5BC04EDEEC830E3E8CDF2CCDB
```

Now, accessing the same image from before, the client will send the session ID in the request and Tomcat will be able to log it

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2017:18:48:09 -0300] "GET /webapp/images/login.png HTTP/1.1" 200 29646 session-id 068FCCF5BC04EDEEC830E3E8CDF2CCDB
```

So no Session Id will be created for images, scripts or other static resources. But it's really up to your implementation or the framework you are using...
And just so you know, the JSESSIONID is in the [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf) (ch 7.1.1 cookies, pg 55).

Comment: I am aware about Spring MVC. Are you saying that angular JS application will not create any session as it would be serving only static contents?

Comment: In your example you are accessing an image (/application/img/sort-icn-down.png) and it doesn't appear to be being handled by a servlet. By the tests I described above in this case no session will be created. But, if your AngularJS client code access some servlet, a session should be created...

Comment: When you asked if a "angular JS application will not create any session as it would be serving only static contents", the answer is yes **IF** the AngularJS layer only consumes static content. But I don't think that would be the case, right? If the AngularJS layer also requests dynamic content from (for a example) a Spring MVC Controller, then a session should be created e returned in the response.

Comment: So you mean to say that, if I host a servlet application, it will take care of creating session but just the angular JS application hosted on tomcat will be as good as static application if it is relying on external service for getting data?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, a client (browser) accessing your application will only request for static content (like scripts and images) from your server. Other requests will be made for another external server. Right? In this case you won't get any session. Remember that a session is suposed to hold data beteween requests... It is not needed when you request static content. Also, the JSESSIONID cookie used by Tomcat to show the session's id in the log is defined by Servlet Specification, therefore you need some implementation of this specification, like Spring MVC. =)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response and comments. I got your point.. :-)

Answer (score -1):

No, Angular JS does not generate a sessionId for you. You should generate and manage your sessionId on the server side.

Comment: I do not have any code on server side. It is just an angular JS application on the front end. I can see the access logs in Tomcat as browser is accessing the pages.

Comment: How to create a session and manage it on server side? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I don't know Tomcat very well but some quick googling should get you the answer you need. It will most likely depend on which version of Tomcat you are using too. It looks like in Tomcat 7 sessionIds may automatically be created. You should post your full tomcat config file and change your question to something like "how do i generate sessions in tomcat in the config file?"

Comment: If Tomcat 7 creates sessions automatically, this should create the sessionId automatically.

Comment: I have searched a lot on google before posting this question on SO and before putting a 50 points bounty on this question.

Comment: this is a tomcat question and not angularjs. you should remove the angularjs tags, and reformat your question like i said above to draw attention to that. someone more experienced in tomcat should be able to help you. also posting your full config file may help too

Comment: why did you down vote this answer? I answered the question you asked and even helped guide you to reformat the question

Comment: Because this is not an answer to the question. It would be great if you could provide me the implementation.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala - _I do not have any code on server side_ -- then what's running on tomcat?

Comment: Tomcat is just serving the web pages as a web server. I am making ajax calls to services installed on a different servers to fetch the data.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala your stated question is "Does angular js application create session id automatically?" and I provided an answer to it. Again, you should update your question to make it clearer for anyone viewing and looking to answer.